# Hibernate setParemeter 1-based or 0-based? QueryParameterException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x

Assuming everything else works like a charm (entities, named queries, native named queries) I'm facing weird exceptions while trying to run following query, where date column type is `TIMESTAMP`:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "problematicQuery", query = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date < ?")
```

I'm trying to execute this query using following code, where date is `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
Query deleteQuery = em.createNativeQuery("problematicQuery");
deleteQuery.setParameter(1, date);
deleteQuery.executeUpdate();
```

This code results in following exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
```

When I change the middle code line to this:

```
Query deleteQuery = em.createNativeQuery("problematicQuery");
deleteQuery.setParameter(0, date);
deleteQuery.executeUpdate();
```

I'll get the same exception with different position:

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 0
```

I'm using JBoss 7.2.0.Final (Hibernate version is 4.2.0.CR1), Oracle 11g.

WHAT IS WRONG ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you use wrong way

```
em.createNamedQuery("problematicQuery")
```

rather than

```
em.createNativeQuery("problematicQuery");
```

In your case a query created from string "problematicQuery" where no parameters exist

Comment: That make sense, thanks! Will try. BTW I have originally used it like you're saying together with named parameter but I faced other problem I don't remember... Ok let's get back where I started :-).

Comment: The original exception and the reason why I swithced to createNativeQuery was "Named query not found." exception. Which now I also know why did not work. So... problem solved :-). Thank you! (I feel embarrassed for such obvious mistake).

Answer (score 1):

You should use named parameters inside  JPA QL: `@NamedNativeQuery(name = "problematicQuery", query = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE date < :dt"`

and `deleteQuery.setParameter("dt", date);`

Comment: I used it this way before I changed it ( I'm using named params everywhere else but this query). Original problem with this approach was  org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [date]. And I checked it dozen times for a typo etc. I've found here in SO that named queries are not defined for native queries so I started playing with positional like described in my question.

Comment: Reason is the same as @StanislavL explained